# update date format

Tags: php, html

I am unable to update mysql date

trying ,

mysql is remaining 0000-00-00 when inserting date format `date('d-m-Y')`

thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
date('Y-m-d')
```

Also, if you just want to use the current time/date and your MySQL server is in the same timezone as your web server, you can [use `NOW()` in your SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now) instead.

Comment: Thanks Brad it worked but I want to have this format d-m-Y when I output the date to the table

Comment: @user1347219, You must use this format when inserting data into your data.  If you want to format the data when you output it **from** the table, then you should do that with PHP:  `date('d-m-Y', strtotime($your_mysql_date))`  Don't store formatted dates in the database.  Use datetime or timestamp columns as appropriate, and leave formatting of data up to PHP.